# Wanting to have a prefix id with number stored in db

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a table for a prefix field I want a three chracter prefeix and then a number So I am using a table called nextId but for some reason it is not saving and updating the table with the new value does anbody have an idea what is going wrong here.

So in the db I have this below and then after i use that id it should autoincrement it 2 , 3 , 4 and so on  and display it with padding of five zeros.

But the poblem I am having is its not saving the values back to the db i e its not incrementing the value.

> PREFIX FHS NEXT ID = 1

```
public string GetPrefix(string section)
 {
        int nextId = -1;
        string Prefix = "";
        try
        {
            section = section.ToUpper();

            var q = from n in apertureNetEntities.tblApertureNetPrefixes where n.section == section select n;

            tblApertureNetPrefix nextIdEntity = q.ToList()[0];

            nextId = Convert.ToInt32(nextIdEntity.nextId);
            Prefix = nextIdEntity.prefix;
            nextIdEntity.nextId = nextId + 1;
            SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            string inner = string.Empty;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }
            logger.Error("Error in GetPrefix function aperturenetdal " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an `IDENTITY`-column which does auto-increment it's value? Your approach is not safe at all(consider race conditions, multi-threading or even multiple applications).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am aware of using unique identifer etc but I am wanting to create a custom prefixer id If you can share with me a bettter answer then please do so. I am using entity framework btw so it needs to account for that the answer

Comment: i don't understand why you can't use an `IDENTITY` column for the number portion and prepend the prefix in the query.

Comment: cause im not updating the row until the record is saved complety please provide a example within the context and ill mark as the answer